# Kernal Smoothing for long vectors in R

Tags: r, smoothing

I currently trying to use the variables phihatvec and g1barvec predict the gammavec values.

I am trying to use the ksmooth function in R to accomplish this task. However, I keep recieving an error. Here is my code:

```
myksmooth=ksmooth(c(phihatvec, g1barvec), gammavec, kernel = "normal", bandwidth = 2)
scatter3D(phihatvec,g1barvec, myksmooth[[2]], phi=0, bty="g")
```

Here is my error:

> scatter3D(phihatvec,g1barvec, myksmooth, phi=0, bty="g")
>   Error in scatter3D(phihatvec, g1barvec, myksmooth, phi = 0, bty = "g") : 
>     'z' should have same length as 'x'

Could anyone help me with my problem?

Thank you in advance!